# input box disable stay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a checkbox and when I click that checkbox it disables but when I refresh the page it does back to not being disabled how do I make it stay disabled

```js
$( "input[type='checkbox']").click(function(event){
  $(this).attr('disabled', true);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='checkbox' name='checkbox' id='checkBox' class='checkBox' />
```

Comment: You have to store checkbox value in db and have to add consition in html using php

Comment: Store data on db or localStorage.

Answer (score 2):

Set the flag for the Checkbox, when you click it change the flag status into 'true', Then store it into your Local storage. Now, the checkbox value will display if you refresh the page. I don't know Javascript syntax. I,m Angular 2+ Typescript.

Answer (score 1):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#checkBox1').click(function (event) {
                $(this).attr('disabled', true);
                localStorage.setItem('check', 1);

            });
            var chk = localStorage.getItem('check');
            if (chk) {
                $('#checkBox1').attr('disabled', true);
                $('#checkBox1').attr('checked', true);
            }
        });</script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
       <input type='checkbox' name='checkbox' id='checkBox1' class='checkBox' />

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but if I have more than one checkbox when the first one gets checked then all the other checkboxes get checked

Comment: Use Id at the place of class in jquery. It will work . Please mark the answer.

Comment: sorry I am only 10 yrs old but could you pls give me a example code

Comment: Hi buddy I have make changes in my code you can use this and reslove your query.

Comment: hello Akhil Singh When I tried the code it didn't work because I have multiple checkboxes any other suggestion's

Comment: hi buddy , Do ypu want to use of this code for all checkboxes or only one this is work for only one checkbox. if you want to use for all checkboxes then you should use (.checkBox) at the place of (#checkBox).